# JavaScript variable doesn't work in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

All the pages in my website has the same header. I implemented that like this:

```
extends('layouts.main')
```

Now in some pages, I need to send a successful message and in other pages not. I implemented that like this:

```
return....->with(array(
sucessfulMessage => 'asdf'
));
```

Please note that I do that just in some pages not in all pages.

Now I want to use that variable in JavaScript. I did this in the layout.main:

```
<head>
    {{ HTML::script('/js/jquery-2.1.1.js')}}
    @if(isset($successfulMessage))
    <script>
        var successfulMessage = "{{$successfulMessage}}";
    </script>
    @endif
    {{ HTML::script('/js/myPopupScript.js')}}
</head>
```

and then in `myPopupScript.js` I did this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(!typeof successfulMessage === 'undefined'){
        alert(successfulMessage);
    }else{
        alert("test");
    }
});
```

#### My problem

The alert is always `test` even though when the successfulMessage has been sent.

#### Important note

When I use F12 in Google Chrome to see the actual HTML, I can see this:

```
<script>
        var successfulMessage = "asdf";
    </script>
```

so the variable is defined.

Comment: `!typeof successfulMessage === 'undefined'` = `(!(typeof sucessfullMessage)) === 'undefined'` = `false === 'undefined'` = `false`.

Comment: @Cthulhu couldn't understand your comment, could you explain please?

Comment: Just saying that if correct operators precedence taken into account, your condition will never hold. What you wanted is `typeof successfulMessage !== 'undefined'`.

Comment: @Cthulhu you right, because I tried to define the variable before the condition and still not working. that a good notice, please how to solve it?

Comment: The real problem here is that when you try to access the variable `successfulMessage` never has assigned the php value, remember php executes is server-side and the script load at first.

Comment: @martinezjc so when I defined the varible in the blade, I am doing that in the server? and the client side javascript has no idea about it? that is your point?

Comment: Remember that blade templates are php code :) in another hand you define the javascript variable in the template but when it loads the template the document.ready executes at first and in that point the variable that you pass in the view is not yet render

Comment: @martinezjc there must be a way because the first answer here works just when the variable is exist,but then the user edited his code and I can't re find it :(

Comment: @martinezjc try catch ? ?please anything . I must make it work

Comment: @martinezjc it seems that is your answer my friend :) :) please re write it. i though you are another guy :) so sorry

Comment: let me do an example, wait a min :P, you can alert in `$(document).ready` the value of the var successfulMessage and see which is the content

Comment: @martinezjc take your time and when you need me to do anything kindly tell me. many thanks

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent Well did you just try to replace your condition with what I suggested?

Comment: Just checking: you have `sucessfulMessage => 'asdf'` with only one `c` I guess that's a typo in your question that is not present in your code?

Comment: @lowerends I solve it I will write the answer now

Comment: @martinezjc I solved it, I will write the answer

Comment: @Cthulhu I solved it, I will write the answer.

Comment: good for you i was close to publish my answer :P

Comment: @martinezjc I was faster :P :P

Answer (score 1):

The code that works for me is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var typeOfSuccessfulMessage = typeof successfulMessage;

    if(typeOfSuccessfulMessage == 'string'){
       alert(successfulMessage);
    }else{
        alert("undefined");
    }
});
```

Many thanks for @martinezjc,  @lowerends and @Cthulhu

Comment: @martinezjc I need two day to accept my own answer :) but truly I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Change this piece of code:

**Edit**:

Try to change the condition in your if/else javascript block

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     @if(isset($successfulMessage))
        var successfulMessage = {{$successfulMessage}};
    @endif

    if( !typeof successfulMessage === 'undefined' ) {
        alert("test");
    } else {
        alert(successfulMessage);
    }
});
```

Hope this works :)

Comment: your new code works just when the variable is defined, but where there is no variable, I got this error message: `Uncaught ReferenceError: successfulMessage is not defined `

Comment: your second new code has a syntax error, can't write `@` inside a jquery function

Comment: I checked and told you. can't' write @ in a jquery